# Почему bash ругается на комментарий?

Tags: ubuntu, wsl2

Запускаю скрипт **script.sh** :

```
sh script.sh
```

В итоге он ругается на строчку:

```
export $(cat ~app/.env/my_env| xargs)
```

> script.sh: 5: export: #: bad variable name

В этой строке находится комментарий:

```
# Параметры для запуска
```

Почему он ругается на комментарий разве не должен его пропускать?

Запускаю скрипт через WSL(Ubuntu 22.04) на Windows10

Comment: не должен. Попробуйте в консоли написать `export '#'` и получите такую же ошибку. А что вы пытаетесь сделать таким странным способом?

Comment: Закинуть в переменные в переменные окружения из файла my_env

Comment: А банальный `. ~app/.env/my_env` чем не устраивает?

Comment: ... или менее банальный `source ~app/.env/my_env`?